# How to change ParentActivity programmatically?

Tags: android

We can set parent activity like this

```
 <activity
        android:name=".ui.launch.SignUpActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_sign_up"
        android:parentActivityName=".ui.launch.LoginActivity" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTION"
            android:value=".ui.launch.LoginActivity" />
```

But how can I change the parent activity programmatically?

Comment: why do you want to do that

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest that you don't specify parent activity at all in this case. Instead override [onBackPressed()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onBackPressed()) event in your activity and lunch new activity yourself:

```
@Override public void onBackPressed(){
    finish();
    if(condition){
        launchActivity1();
    }else{
        launchActivity2();
    }
}
```

Comment: Mentioning parent activity allows you to have the back arrow at the top. Is it still available in this case?